# Elixir + Phoenix: Where do I put application initializers?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I am looking into using the Amnesia package: https://github.com/meh/amnesia

One of the requirements in addition to defining my database / schema is running the line `Amnesia.start`. I would like to do this in an initializer. Coming from Rails, this would supposedly go into `config/intiailizers/`

Where do I put this line in a Phoenix app?

Comment: You can add `amnesia` in your application function in `mix.exs`.So Amnesia will start when you start your application

Comment: oooo what exaclty does that do? does that just call `[[package name]].start` under the hood?

Comment: Yes exactly!.You can read more about mix project here: http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/mix/Mix.html

Comment: Great thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

You should almost always put the application name in the applications list in your `mix.exs` file, even if the package does not have startup code. If you use a package like `exrm` or `distillery` to build a production release, it will need your packages listed so it knows to build them into the release.

Also, if you want to start otp based processes that create, you need to start them in your application file `lib/my_project.ex`. You should see some boilerplate in there like `worker(MyProject.MyAwsomeService, [])`.